# Changing values of a multiple select box when selecting the value of other

Tags: jquery, select

I have two multiple `select` boxes and have made a function where when I change the value of the first I want to change the `value` of the second... But it is not working... Can you please help me?

Here is the code:

first combo:

```
<div style="margin-left: 161px;">
<select id="media" class="chzn-done ready valid" onchange="ObterPublicacoes(this.value);" name="media" data-size="small" multiple="" style="display: none;">
<div id="media_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-multi chzn-container-active" style="width:100%;">
</div>
```

Function:

```
function ObterPublicacoes(teste) {
    document.getElementById('publicacao').options.length = 0;
    document.getElementById('publicacao').innerHTML = '<option value="" >publicacoes</option><option value="" >publicacoes2</option>'
}
```

Second combo after change:

```
<select id="publicacao" class="dualselects" name="publicacao" data-size="small" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
    <option value=''>publicacoes</option>
    <option value=''>publicacoes2</option>
</select>
```

you can see it changes the values but not on right side... How can I change in the right side?

Comment: The first select has no options?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick jQuery example for you:

HTML:

```
<select id="selectOne" class="selectBoxGroup">
    <option>Value One</option>
    <option>Value Two</option>
    <option>Value Three</option>
</select>

<select id="selectTwo" class="selectBoxGroup">
    <option>Value One</option>
    <option>Value Two</option>
    <option>Value Three</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(document).on('change', '.selectBoxGroup', function() {
        $('.selectBoxGroup').val($(this).val());
    });

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lz8DH/